# Find values of $\theta$ for which the (random) series converges

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d Uniform$[0,1]$ random variables. Find all values of $\theta > 0$ for which,
>
> $$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(X_n + \frac{1}{n^\theta}\right)^{n^{\theta+1}} $$
>
> converges with probability $1$.

Suppose $\theta \leq 1$. Then, for any $C > 0$,

$$ P\left(\left(X_n + \frac{1}{n^\theta}\right)^{n^{\theta+1}} > C\right) = P\left(X_n + \frac{1}{n^\theta} > C^{n^{-(\theta+1)}}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{n^\theta} - C^{n^{-(\theta+1)}} $$

Since $\theta \leq 1$, there exists no $C > 0$, for which the following series will converge,

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^\theta} - C^{n^{-(\theta+1)}}\right) $$

Thus by the necessity part of the Three Series Theorem, the above series diverges for $\theta \leq 1$.

I'm having difficulty for $\theta > 1$ though. If $C = 1$, then above series certainly converges. However, we would need to check convergence of the series,

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty E\left[\left(X_n + \frac{1}{n^\theta}\right)^{2n^{\theta+1}}\right] $$

Any hints on how to do so?

Comment: Hint: Forget expectations. If $\theta>1$, show that $$X_n<1-\frac2{n^\theta}$$ for every $n$ large enough, and proceed.

Comment: Ah thank you. I was curious as towhy that inequality held for large $n$ but then I realized it is a simple application of Borel-Cantelli.